# Restricting visibility to Contact records based on a field

Tags: sharing-rule, owd

I'm trying to lock down visibility to certain contacts in SFDC.

We have a field on Contact that is populated by a Flow and it is one value that we care about. The field is called 'Record Type Account'. If the value is "Tenant", no commercial person must be able to see those contacts, only support teams. (and it cannot be a formula field I am willing to bet...)

I have changed the org-wide default of the contact object to private, to lock it down from everyone but the record owners.

Then I added a rule where it says 'Record Type Account' not equal to "Tenant' then share with the 'Marketing' role and its subordinates. The role hierarchy is set up with this in mind and sits on top of the commercial hierarchy (but below the admin).

And whenever I try to set up the rule it just opens up everything. The field filters make no difference...

Would lvoe your help, please!

Comment: Where do support users sit in the role hierarchy? Have you checked if the support user profile has View All or Modify All on the custom object?

Comment: _And whenever I try to set up the rule it just opens up everything_ - unclear what you mean by that. Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour). Take a look at [another Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/379494/salesforce-not-enforcing-users-in-this-role-cannot-access-opportunities-that-th) that is almost a doppelganger of yours.